# my next js project is not running on the localhost

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Create a project in next js with the npx create-next-app command

It is a login that contains next-auth. The first time I executed the code, the localhost responded with the next.js main page.

I made some changes and when I refreshed the page it did not reload the local host

I use the npm run dev command and it does not give me any results, I tried to create the same project from another PC and the same thing happens to me, the local host page does not load

I hope you can help me, I don't know what it could be, I'm new to developing, anything is helpful):

Comment: what changes you made? have you tried opening http://localhost:3000 manually?

Comment: They were code changes, nothing that would affect the functionality of the localhost, I don't know how I could change it manually, as I'm telling you, I'm new and I was following a tutorial

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.